Issue with configuring primary color in Flutter
I wanted to change the primary color of my Flutter app from theme data, but it is not applying to the AppBar.
I began using primarySwatch, but after reading that primarySwatch is being shut down, I used ColorScheme.fromSeed(), yet that did not work either. Here is the code for the main app:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:to_do/home_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.yellow),
      ),
    );
  }
}


The HomePage() app's code is as follows:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[200],
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );
  }
}


I have not given the appbar a manual color, as I expected it to change automatically based on theme, but that is not working and it stays white.
I would appreciate it if anyone had any ideas.
Thanks.

because ThemeData has separate property to define appear theme        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: Colors.red),

To use an automatic background color from the ThemeData, provide surface:Colors.green within the ColorScheme, as shown below
ThemeData(
 colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
        seedColor:Colors.blue,
        surface:Colors.green,
      ),
);

This will automatically pick a green background color for your AppBar.
